# What is the "best" free CMS for my needs?

Tags: content-management-system

I have the task to build a web-site for a smaller non-profit organization. I have a bit experience with ASP.NET but because ASP.NET hosting is rather expensive here in germany (we will also need a lot of webspace and traffic) and aslo because there are quite a hughe list of features I think I should go with a PHP/MySQL based CMS (correct me if I am wrong). The question is wich one? There are are so many free CMSs out there. If I tell you what I need, can you tell me what would be a good choice?

Here are my requirement (sorted by priority):

1. **Ease of use** (installation, configuration, maintainance) for me who builds the site but also for the members of the organisation they must be able to easily change the the content of *some* main pages, add supages, add a new mailinglist upload a file to the repository etc.
2. A **membership/role management system**. Based on the role of a member access to certain subpages, subforums or folders in the file management system etc. must be restricted. Only certain roles must be allowed to add new mailinglists or moderate the forum.
3. A **mailingsystem** that allows me or the members of the organistation to add new adresses, maillinglists or newsletters.
4. A **file management system**. Members should be able to upload arbitary files on the server and browse them via a web frontent. Access to folder should be restrictable based on the member rights.
5. A pulbic **forum** with private subforums.
6. **Localization**. As much as possible of the final site (if not everything) that is presented to the visitor of the site as well as to the members who maintain the site should be presented in german.
7. Good control over **design/look and feel** of the overall site. I should have good control over how I want the site to look like.
8. A lively **community** with enough momentum to find **ressources and help** when I am lost.
9. **Extensibility**. In case there are some smaller features missing or f the behavior of an existing feature is not quite the way I want it, it would be cool to easily add it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by others, Joomla might be a good option for you, although Wordpress may also work (and it's easier). However, I highly recommend that you check out [OpenSourceCMS.com](http://opensourcecms.com/), which hosts demos for many of the free and open source CMS's, blogs, forums, shopping carts, etc. For most of them, you can try out both the admin and the frontend. Spend some time looking them over and then when you find some that you like, investigate them further by going to their websites.

Comment: After trying out the demo, I think Typo3 would drive me a little nuts, honestly. It doesn't seem very intuitive. Joomla's interface is a lot easier. As far as features go, I don't think you're going to find very many CMS's with more extensions than Joomla. Wordpress maybe, Drupal maybe. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

[Concrete5](http://www.concrete5.org/) is a new Content management system that is excellent. Easily themable, user friendly, great little dashboard for management

and it's open source

Answer (score 2):

My vote would be [Joomla](http://joomla.org).  It has most fot he features you discussed, if not in the core as an extension, component or theme.  I've set several up and rarely have to use any coding during setup, plus there's a vibrant community if you need help.  It also integrates nicely with other 'best of breed' apps like BB forums, Coppermine photo gallery's and others.

Answer (score 2):

[Joomla!](http://joomla.org) would seem to fit your needs, and I'd also suggest [Kunena](http://www.kunena.com/) for the forum (which integrates with Joomla) and [DOCman](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/82/details) for the file management solution.

Comment: Hi! I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Typo3, so I can't really comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd suggest Drupal for any sort of advanced web site. While Joomla! and similar systems are a bit easier to get started with, Drupal's a lot more flexible and extensible.

You want full control over theming? Or user authentication? Access control? Database queries? User picture scaling? Tagclouds?
It's there when you need it :)

Comment: Well, I haven't worked with Typo3 for some time, but last time I checked, it was suffering from the dreaded Inner Platform Effect. They have their own scripting language, a kernel, etc.

Personal taste may vary, but I'm not very fond of large, monolithic systems like Typo3.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [Joomla](http://joomla.org) too, even though I'm a ASP.NET developer.
Joomla is very flexible and customizable, so it fills all your need, because of the big community.

Comment: What do you think of Typo3? It seems to be very good featurewise. How does it compare to Joomla?

Answer (score 1):

As a complete CMS noob, I asked myself the same question. I started with Drupal. Sure you can do lots of things with it. Very extensible and customizable.

But after implementing my first site in Drupal, I decided to create the next one in Joomla, to have a frame of comparison. Conclusion: Joomla is a looooooooooooot easier to get started and takes a lot less time to create a functioning website from scratch. Sure, for very big projects, Drupal lets you customize more, but for the type of project you suggest: I would recommend Joomla...

Comment: What do you think of Typo3? It seems to be very good featurewise. How does it compare to Joomla?

Comment: Don't have any experience with it, but judging from the website description and screenshots/movies it seems Joomla is easier... (backend-wise, for users with no real IT background)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this PDF report comparing](http://www.idealware.org/comparing_os_cms/idealware_comparing_os_cms_report.pdf) WordPress, Joomla, Drupal and Plone quite helpful when I was asking myself the same question recently.  Nice comments with a focus on non-profits - find the comparison summary/recommendation on pp 13-14.

Definitely read the report because it talks about the strengths/issues of each package - given your prioritized list of features, I'd recommend [**Joomla**](http://www.joomla.org).  I think you can do what you want with reasonable effort and good recent modules like [DocMan](http://www.joomlatools.eu/products/docman.html).  WordPress is awesome for a blogging site, but lacks a number (2,3,4,9) of your requirements, and though Drupal is powerful and flexible, it definitely has a steep learning curve.  Plone even more so.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'd vote for [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com), it's ASP.Net but that saves you the overhead of learning a complete new environment, language and tool just to implement a 'free' CMS, realistically how much is your time worth? It meets all your criteria, and there are currently 600,000 users - which means that you can just get on with it, somewhere someone has already worked on your problems for you.

As for expensive hosting, why not host in another country, I get US$5/month for DotNetNuke in the states, and I code from Australia.

Comment: We will need a lot of webspace (1-2GB) and traffic and we HAVE to use a german provider.

Comment: Definitely NOT DNN, as someone who has to fight with it with each day, I'd say it's probably one of the worst 'BIG' content management systems out there

Comment: If your looking for a lot of features, DNN has many, many modules available. http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=295&categoryid=13

Comment: @kitsune - could you provide some objective examples?

Answer (score 0):

Ive had some experience with [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/). Highly customizable, plenty of plugins and one of the liveliest communities in development. It has a great admin panel also.

Comment: What do you think of Typo3? It seems to be very good featurewise. How does it compare to Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as told by [Tom Deleu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26579/tom-deleu), yes, though Drupal is very capable and strong CMS but it is tough and complicated to work on. Coming to another option of CMS that is [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/). Though it is very easy to develop a content based websites with wordpress but with very limited scope and flexibility.

As per your requirement my vote will also go to [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/). It is very user friendly, optimized and a CMS you can rely on. Small applications as mentioned by you like "mailing system", "File system" etc. suits joomla more than others.