# Is there any cushycms alternative?

Tags: content-management-system

I need a free very simple CMS which i can host on my own server just like Cushy CMS www.cushycms.com. is there any ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently wrote an alternative to CushyCMS because I wanted the open source community to have a free alternative.

[Mechedit](http://code.google.com/p/mechedit/) is an open source CushyCMS like applciation.  Runs on PHP5 only though.

Answer (score 2):

[Orbis CMS](http://www.novo-ws.com/orbis-cms) is another open source alternative to CushyCMS. It's built on the same pricinples (simplicity, ease-of-use) and features a stylish interface, but is self-hosted and free.

Answer (score 1):

SnappySnippets is a free and simple alternative; it is highly customizable and has a desktop interface that your clients will find easy to use. It is hosted so that you don't have to install anything

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions like this on Stackover flow
for example:
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618685/what-is-the-best-free-cms-for-my-needs)

Just search for CMS

Answer (score 0):

Good question which I was asking myself recently. This is a neglected corner of the CMS landscape. However, I did find:

- this rather detailed and intelligent summary list:
  http://www.matthijskamstra.nl/blog/index.php/2011/02/16/lightweight-cms-for-simple-projects/
- a briefer but recently updated list of 40 lightweight CMSs [http://www.abcphp.com/out/top-40-free-simple-lightweight-cms-|-vivalogo-resources/](http://www.abcphp.com/out/top-40-free-simple-lightweight-cms-%7C-vivalogo-resources/)

Two other lists, both from 2012 and neither suggesting much examination of the products:

- http://webdesignledger.com/tools/10-simple-and-light-weight-cms-solutions
- http://speckyboy.com/2010/07/19/14-light-and-east-to-use-open-source-content-management-systems/

In case you're wondering, the project I was looking at using one of these for got a little more complicated and I ended up going to a more heavyweight system, with a simplified interface on top of it.

There's a lesson there. Many systems that will cope with complex needs (Drupal, MODX etc) can still be installed pretty quickly, and your users' needs are only going to grow more complex over time.

That said, I'd still like to think lightweight systems have their place. Let us know what you chose.